# What's the difference between ref and & when assigning a variable from a reference?

Tags: syntax, reference, rust, pattern-matching

What is wrong with this code?

```
fn example() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let &_y = &vec;
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/lib.rs:3:15
  |
3 |     let &_y = &vec;
  |         ---   ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
  |         ||
  |         |data moved here
  |         help: consider removing the `&`: `_y`
  |
note: move occurs because `_y` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
 --> src/lib.rs:3:10
  |
3 |     let &_y = &vec;
  |          ^^
```

and why this is correct?

```
let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
let ref _y = &vec;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pattern binding can take some getting used to ;)

In order to understand what the compiler does, you can use the `let _: () = ...;` trick. By assigning to a variable of type `()`, you force the compiler to print an error message giving you the type it inferred for your variable.

---

In the first example:

```
let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
let &y = &vec;
let _: () = y;
```

we get:

> ```
> error[E0308]: mismatched types
>  --> src/lib.rs:4:13
>   |
> 4 | let _: () = y;
>   |             ^ expected (), found struct `std::vec::Vec`
>   |
>   = note: expected type `()`
>              found type `std::vec::Vec<{integer}>`
> ```

the type of `y` is `Vec<i32>`.

What it means is that you are:

1. Borrowing `vec` into a temporary
2. Attempting to move `vec` into `y`, which is forbidden because `vec` is already borrowed.

The equivalent correct code would be:

```
let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
let y = vec;
```

---

In the second example:

```
let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
let ref y = &vec;
let _: () = y;
```

we get:

> ```
> error[E0308]: mismatched types
>  --> src/lib.rs:4:17
>   |
> 4 |     let _: () = y;
>   |                 ^ expected (), found reference
>   |
>   = note: expected type `()`
>              found type `&&std::vec::Vec<{integer}>`
> ```

Thus `y` is `&&Vec<i32>`.

This let us see that `let ref a = b;` is generally equivalent to `let a = &b;`, and therefore in this case: `let y = &&vec;`.

`ref` is made for destructuring; for example, if you had:

```
let vec = Some(vec![1, 2, 3]);
if let Some(ref y) = vec {
    // use `y` here
}
```

you can use `ref` here to be able to bind `y` to `&Vec<i32>` *without* moving even though `vec` here has type `Option<Vec<i32>>`. Indeed, the purpose of `ref` is to take a reference *inside* an existing object during destructuring.

In general, in a `let` statement, you will not use `ref`.

And since Rust 1.26, `ref` is inferred in pattern matching; see the [stabilization of match ergonomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/49394).

Comment: Is there a legit case where we want to use something like `let &y = &vec;`?

Comment: @WiSaGaN: I cannot think of any.

Comment: @WiSaGaN: This construction may be used for example in closures. It's used in function retain in Vec and so on.

Comment: No-one has said it directly, but it seems worth mentioning for completeness: the `let ref y = &vec;` example is equivalent to `let y = &&vec;`.

Comment: @huon: Good call, I added a little blurb to that effect after showing off the type of `y` in the second case.

Comment: @SergeyBromov: I could not find such construct [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L611), do you have an up to date example? I'd really like the understand the usecase.

Comment: Usually `&`-pattern is not idiomatic - often it is possible to use dereference operator `*`. For example, if a method on an enum accepts `&self`, it is better to write `match *self { Variant1(...) => ... }` instead of `match self { &Variant1(...) => ... }`. However, sometimes it can be used for much clearer code, for example, when you need to process an iterator of tuples with `filter()`: `vec.enumerate().filter(|&(i, ref v)| ...)`. I don't think I've ever seen `&`-pattern in `let` bindings.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: in func. 'retain' I mean that when we pass argument &v[i] to closure |&x| x%2 == 0 we get the simple i32; |x| *x%2 == 0 is equivalent, thus all is OK; in other side if we passed Vec<String> to closure |&x | we get error 'cannot move out of borrowed content', thus |x| is correct, that's why I asked my question.

Comment: @SergeyBromov: Ah! I understand now. Yes indeed pattern matching also applies in closure/functions arguments.

Comment: Note that `ref` is not needed for destructuring anymore. `Some(ref y) = vec` can be written as `Some(y) = &vec` now.

Comment: @Chronial: Hum... match ergonomics, right? I haven't tested with "deep" scenarios, do you know if it would work then too?

Comment: What do you mean with "deep"? This will work also work with arbitrary many levels of nesting.

Comment: @Chronial: Arbitrary many levels is what I was wondering. It would have surprised me if it didn't, but just in case... thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 5):

The same symbol (`&`) is doing two different things when used on the right-end and left-end side of a binding. The left-hand side works like a pattern matching, so:

```
let x = (y, z); // x contains a tuple with value (y, z)
let (a, b) = x  // x is destructured into (a, b), so now
                // a has value y and b has value z
```

In the same way

```
let x = &y; // x is a reference to y
let &z = x; // this is like let &z= &y, so we want z to be y
            // this is equivalent to let z = *x
```

A `ref` binding on the left side is saying "pattern match by reference, not by value". So these two statements are equivalent:

```
let ref y = vec;
let y = &vec;
```

although in a let, the second one is more idiomatic.

You can see more examples on the [pointers/ref chapter on rust by example](http://rustbyexample.com/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_pointers.html)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not need the `&` in your working example. If you use it, you end up with a `&&Vec<_>`, which you don't really need.

```
let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
let ref y = vec;
```

The problem with your first code is that you are doing two things at once. Lets split it up into two:

The first part creates a reference to `vec`

```
let y1 = &vec;
```

The second part (the `&` before the variable binding), [destructures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/patterns.html#destructuring).

```
let &y2 = y1;
```

This means you are trying to move out of the reference, which only works if the type is `Copy`, because then any attempt to move will copy the object instead.