# Where has my value moved to in this match?

Tags: rust

I'm creating a list-like structure with an enum:

```rs
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Cons<T: Clone> {
  Cons(T, Box<Cons<T>>),
  Null
}
```

However, I'm having trouble making a `map` method for this:

```rs
  pub fn map<F,S>(&self, fun: F) -> Cons<S>
    where F: Fn(T) -> S, S: Clone
  {
    match self {
      &Cons::Null => Cons::Null,
      &Cons::Cons(ref head, ref tail) => Cons::new(fun(*head), tail.map(fun)),
    }
  }
```

I'll get this:

```rs
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*head` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/lib.rs:50:56
   |
50 |       &Cons::Cons(ref head, ref tail) => Cons::new(fun(*head), tail.map(fun)),
   |                                                        ^^^^^ move occurs because `*head` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

After some attempts mixing and matching referencing and dereferencing, I gave up and used `clone`:

```rs
&Cons::Cons(ref head, ref tail) => Cons::new(fun(head.clone()), tail.map(fun)),
```

While it works, I'm not quite sure why the value has moved. I read the chapter on [references and borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) in the Rust book, but I didn't find anything there. Also, I have read about [the ref keyword](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.ref.html), but it just seems like the same thing as `&`, but [in destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717001/whats-the-difference-between-ref-and-when-assigning-a-variable-from-a-referen). I even looked at [Rust by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/move.html) for moves and I still don't understand where my `head` has gone to. So uh, can you help me find where my `head` went?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d590786a7bf320e43d9d73fe0636527e)

I *do* understand what borrowing/moves is/are, I just don't understand why it has happened here.

Comment: That's another option on the table yes, but I *really* want to know where my `head` has run off to. I don't see anywhere `head` was used before the call to `fun`. Is it because I used `self` already?

Comment: The receiver of your `map` function is `&self` so you don't own your `Cons` instance. Therefore you can't move any of the internal values of your borrowed `Cons` into the returned `Cons`, which is what you're trying to do when you dereference `*head`.

Comment: So it moved because I tried to "steal" it instead. I didn't think about what `&self` had to do with this. If you add an answer I'll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you take has type `Fn(T) -> S`, it thus consumes the `T` to create the `S` (as a map function should do). You have two options: either

1. change the function type to `Fn(&T) -> S` or
2. keep the function type as is and change the signature to take `self` instead of `&self`.

I would prefer the second solution, as it is the most idiomatic and behaves like options, iterators, etc.

Full code example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Cons<T> {
  Cons(T, Box<Cons<T>>),
  Null
}

impl<T> Cons<T> {
 pub fn map<F,S>(self, fun: F) -> Cons<S>
    where F: Fn(T) -> S
  {
    match self {
      Cons::Null => Cons::Null,
      Cons::Cons(head, tail) => Cons::Cons(fun(head), Box::new(tail.map(fun))),
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1bc054661407a5919fceb1827bbbe253)